# Using Main method in Gluon Application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

My Gluon Application taking so much time to open , I've tried to use Preloader Class showing progress bar , it work for Java fx but not for the gluon , as it hasn't main method to launch the preloader , so where to place this method , or how I can manage launching the classes ?

this code work for normal JavaFX application

```
    public class main {
       public static void main(String[]args) {
          LauncherImpl.launchApplication( App.class, Preloader.class, args);
     }
  }
```

// Edited

my problem here is to know from where I can change the class loading as default and I posted an answer with the way I found

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149177/gluon-android-splash-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it 
in build.gradle update this line by the class you want to load at first
mainClassName = 'com.Package_Name.Class_Name'

Also in Android update this line in the Manifest.xml file at  tag
android:value="com.Package_Name.Class_Name"